# How to only return the nth arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
def h(x,y):
    return x+y
xline = np.linspace(1, 5, 20)
yline = np.linspace(1, 5, 20)
xi = xline
yi = yline
N = 10
for i in range(N):
    xOld = xi
    yOld = yi
    xNew = h(xOld,yOld)
    yNew = xOld
    xi = xNew
    yi = yNew    
    print(xNew[-1],yNew[-1])
```

So here is my code, and I was trying to get only the 10th `xNew` and `yNew`.
And when I `print(xNew[-1],yNew[-1])`, I got the 10th element of all 10 arrays we have. What should I do to get only the 10th `xi` and `yi`? And `xi` ,`yi` should contain 20 elements.

Comment: 1. Post a [mre]. We can't help you if we can't run your code and reproduce your problem. 2. You're operating on the _entire_ array in each iteration, so `xNew` and `yNew` are full arrays. If you want to access the last element, just do `xNew[-1]` or `yNew[-1]`.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion! And I just modify the question. And I also tried as u suggested. But it gives me the 10th element of all 10 arrays we have. What I want should be the 10th array which should contain 20 elements. Could you plz help me with that?

Comment: Are you saying you only care about the values _after the loop is finished?_ In that case, move the `print(xNew, yNew)` statement to _after the loop!_

Comment: Yeah, I care about what is the last `xi` and `yi` after the loop is finished. If I move `print(xNew, yNew)` to after the loop, I only get one element now. What I wish to see is the full 20 elements of `xline` and `yline` at the end of the loop.

Comment: You're probably printing `xNew[-1]`. You need to print `xNew`.

Comment: Thank you so much, man. I'm a math student new to coding so I asked stupid questions like this. Anyway, I appreciate it!